# Reformat line breaks in Vim markdown file

Tags: vim, macvim

I recently converted from [TextMate](http://macromates.com/) to [MacVim](https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim) with [Janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus) for editing my markdown files.

How can I reformat an old markdown file so that lines longer than 79 characters are converted from a single line into multiple lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
:set textwidth=79
```

Then `gggq}`

Comment: Can you please explain what this does? It worked, I'm just curious because it was awesome.

Comment: This is in reference to Kyle's question above: The command `:set` allows you to change vim's config in the local instance (as opposed to putting this setting in ~/.vimrc and making it persist to all instances). The next line can be broken down to smaller parts. First, `gg` is an motion moving you to the top of the page (usually, see http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#gg). And `gq}` is a text-formatting command (explained here http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#gq)